# Glassfish doctype description files missing

Tags: glassfish, deployment-descriptor

In the glassfish-web.xml you have the doctype description file linked, like http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd.

This is downloaded and parsed by glassfish, when our application is deployed. glassfish.org is not available anymore so we changed to http://glassfish.java.net, but even that is not available anymore. Does anybody know, where to find the dtd's?

Maybe we could embed the dtd's as a permanent solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a little bit confusing because these files are actually NOT downloaded from the internet, this would mean that nobody could deploy anything without a connection to the internet.

The files are located in `<YOUR_GLASSFISH_FOLDER>/glassfish/lib/dtds/`

If you get an error message which says it can't locate the DTD to validate, you may have a formatting error in your XML file. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27877591/how-do-i-eliminate-my-glassfish-java-ee-applications-dependency-on-the-internet) for more details.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification! Now, I just have trouble understanding what problem we had before :D